# Need help in adding functionality to MIPS single cycle datapath?

Tags: mips

I'm trying to add functionality to these datapaths so that it can read the following instruction:

ADDNEW X, Y, Z

if (Y > Z) X = Y+ Z

else X = MEM[Y+Z]

Not really sure where to start.. so any hints are appreciated. I think I need to rewrite the result of the slt somewhere to tell it which way to go.. but not sure how? Yes is for homework so not expecting answers.. just hopefully a direction. Thank you..

[image: first]

[second http://www.utdallas.edu/~cantrell/ee4304/Pipe-data+control.jpg](http://www.utdallas.edu/~cantrell/ee4304/Pipe-data+control.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The top design is a single cycle and the bottom design is a pipeline design.