# Why do call and jump instruction use a displacement relative to the next instruction, not current?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, machine-code, relative-addressing

In the table below extracted from Intel's docs we have for the opcodes E8 *cw* and E8 *cd* that the displacement is relative to the next instruction.

Why the next instruction? Why isn't the displacement relative to the [`call`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/call) instruction itself?

[image]

Comment: Historical hardware reasons. You can imagine the cpu already fetched the current instruction so the PC is already pointing to the next instruction. Nowadays that's of course not relevant. Alternative explanation: the cpu would continue with the next instruction so the offset says how much to deviate from that.

Comment: @Jester In the example that I'm testing, the cpu is pointing to the call instruction. It hasn't fetched it yet.

Comment: By the time it needs to use the offset, it obviously has fetched it since that very offset is embedded in the instruction.

Comment: Doing things that way made the original 8086 processor easier to design and implement. The design has been carried forward for compatibility reasons. (For example, the address of the next instruction already had to be calculated in order to be used as the return address. May as well use the value you already have!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL:DR: you find the end of the instruction during decode anyway, and to set up decode of the next instruction.  It's very normal for CPUs to do relative addressing relative to the *end* of the current instruction, although some CPUs make different choices like relative to end of next instruction (for ARM PC-relative memory addressing).

**See [Does Program Counter hold current address or the address of the next instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52019437/does-program-counter-hold-current-address-or-the-address-of-the-next-instruction)**

---

x86 machine-code design was set in stone in the late 70's with 8086, except for things (like 32/64-bit ModRM+SIB addressing modes) that got redesigned when extending the ISA.

Original 8086 decoded instruction bytes sequentially (not necessarily a whole instruction at once), and had no upper limit on number of prefix bytes or total instruction length.

**I *think* 8086 avoided *ever* needing to save the starting address of an instruction,** even for exceptions.  For example, on modern x86 `#DE` (divide exception) pushes the address of the faulting instruction.  But [on 8086 the exception frame has the address of the *next* instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57171220/x86-program-counter-abstracted-from-microarchitecture#comment100887215_57172505).

8086 even has a "bug" (or documented design flaw) where interrupts that arrive during execution of `cs rep movsb` (for example) push the address of the final prefix as the exception-return address, making segment overrides on `rep`-string instructions essentially unusuable with interrupts enabled.  (Because execution will resume either without the `rep` or without the segment override, whichver you put first).  See [x86 Program Counter abstracted from microarchitecture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57171220/x86-program-counter-abstracted-from-microarchitecture) and comments.

---

**When 8086 finishes decoding a `call` instruction, it doesn't know where it started.  The only reference point it has is the end of the `call` instruction.**  So if they wanted to do that optimization in hardware (of not keeping the decode-start address anywhere), they didn't even have a choice.  Although they could in theory have used the address of the `E8 call` opcode (after any prefixes) as the anchor, that would probably have taken an extra adder or extra hardware to record that separately.

Fetch/decode already has to find the end of the instruction during decode (while figuring out that it's a `call` or `jmp`), so the end-of-instruction / address-of-next-instruction is already internally available.  `call` even has to push that value on the stack as the return address.

A pipelined RISC, or a completely unpipelined CPU, would also use that next-instruction address for fetch of the next instruction from memory or I-cache.  But in practice 8086 prefetch is asynchronous into a small prefetch buffer.  The machine-code format was designed on paper mostly before design of the implementation so this common reason for making things relative to the end of an instruction may have been what the architect had in mind.

It's a common design choice for many ISAs to make branches relative to the end of the instruction.

---

Just to reiterate, the reason I'm talking only about 8086 (which is internally *very* different from modern x86) is that it was the *first* gen, and understanding it helps explain some machine-code design decisions.  (e.g. why x86 spends 8 opcodes on single-byte `xchg [e/r]ax, reg` : because 8086 didn't have `movsx` or 2-operand `imul`, and needed or wanted AX for a lot of stuff.  Also that code-size was the major bottleneck for performance.)

Modern x86 just keeps track of every instruction's address and can use that when decoding `call rel32`.  Not a big deal.  [Why do x86 jump/call instructions use relative displacements instead of absolute destinations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46184755)

Comment: About `cs rep movsb`: you can work around this by placing the `rep` prefix first and executing `rep cs movsb` repeatedly until `cx` contains `0`.